# Multiply matrix columns by array element-twise

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, multiplication

I have this matrix:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [4, 5, 6]]
```

and this array:

```
[2, 4, 0.5]
```

I would like to multiply every row by the array elementwise:

```
[[2, 8, 1.5],
 [0, 4, 0],
 [8, 20, 3]]
```

And also, the same but with columns:

```
[[2, 4, 6],
 [0, 4, 0],
 [2, 2.5, 3]]
```

How can I do?

@John

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

mx = np.matrix([[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]])
print 'matrix:'
print mx
print '\n'

v = np.array([20,0,10,5])
print 'narray'
print v
print '\n'
```

I cannot get what I need:

```
print mx * v

ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (1,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

And:

```
print mx * v.reshape(-1,1)

[[  0]
 [ 35]
 [105]
 [245]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first is trivial:

```
a * b
```

For the second, here's one way:

```
a * b[:,np.newaxis]
```

That first converts the 3-vector `b` to a 3x1 matrix.  It is equivalent to:

```
a * b.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Or:

```
(a.T * b).T
```

Comment: Note that b[:, np.nexaxis] is equivalent to b[:, None]. So, the whole operation is given by `a * b * b[:, None]`.